# Is it possible to play video in JupyerNotebook as a return of function?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I am doing a CV project and going through the raw videos, trying to make a class that supports playing video in slicing `__getitem__` function, like class[0] will return info of the first video and also play it inline in JupyterNotebook, so I can check what's in the video manually.

I tried:

```
from IPython.display import Video

class MyClass():

    ...(where I load the video list and other info)

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        Video(data=file_path[index], embed=True, mimetype='mp4')
```

but the seems it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, just use the display function.

```
from IPython.display import display, Video
display(Video(data=file_path))
```